# RabbitMQ on Docker: Permission denied when chown-ing erlang cookie

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-volume

I use Kitematic to manage my containers. I run rabbitmq on docker and it's running. The problem is when I configure its volume. Whenever I set local folder for its volume (in Kitematic) it will stop, start, and print the following error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/rabbitmq/.erlang.cookie': Permission denied
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: why do you want to mount a local volume for rmq?

Comment: @DerickBailey I want to persist all my channels, exchanges, and queues

Comment: you can stop and restart the same container, and all changes within that container will persist. if you need to rebuild the container, they would disappear, though

Comment: @DerickBailey turns out I should wrote `{ persistent: true }` while using amqplib to persist my messages.

Comment: Did someone solved that issue?

Answer (score 3):

this should fix it `chmod 600 /path/to/your/local/volume/.erlang.cookie`

Found the answer in https://serverfault.com/questions/406712/rabbitmq-erlang-cookie.

I had the same issue and this fix it. The error message being returned is missing the part about `must be accessible by owner only`